# Swift 3 Space Shooting Game: Issue with bullet collision

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, collision-detection, collision

[image]

I am trying to create a shooting game written in Swift 3. Currently having difficulties with getting collision to work properly. If a bullet hits an enemy, I need an explosion to happen then remove that particular enemy and bullet from the game. If a player hits an enemy, I need an explosion to happen between, then remove that particular enemy and player from the screen and call it gameover. This is what I have so far, bullets just bounces around without collision happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

enum CollisonType: UInt32 {
    case player = 1
    case ammo = 2
    case enemy = 4
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var starfield: SKEmitterNode!
    var player: SKSpriteNode!
    var ammo: SKSpriteNode!
    var enemy: SKSpriteNode!
    var gameScore: SKLabelNode!
    var score: Int = 0 {
        didSet { // didSet a property observer used to update gameScore
            gameScore.text = "Score: \(score)"
        }
    }

    var possibleEnemies = ["ball", "hammer", "tv"]
    var gameTimer: Timer! // Used to create enemies regularly.
    var isGameOver = false //  a boolean that will be set to true when we should stop increasing the player's score

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        starfield = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Starfield")!
        starfield.position = CGPoint(x: 1024, y: 384)
        starfield.advanceSimulationTime(10)
        addChild(starfield)
        starfield.zPosition = -1

        player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player")
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 384)
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: player.texture!, size: player.size)
        player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisonType.player.rawValue
        player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisonType.enemy.rawValue
        addChild(player)

        gameScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        gameScore.text = "Score: 0"
        gameScore.horizontalAlignmentMode = .left
        gameScore.position = CGPoint(x: 8, y: 8)
        addChild(gameScore)

        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0) 
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(createEnemy), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(createAmmo), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func createAmmo() {
        if isGameOver {
            return
        }

        ammo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
        ammo.name = "ammo"
        ammo.position = CGPoint(x: player.position.x + 100, y: player.position.y)
        addChild(ammo)

        ammo.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: ammo.texture!, size: ammo.size)
        ammo.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisonType.ammo.rawValue
        ammo.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisonType.enemy.rawValue

        ammo.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: 900, dy: 0)
        ammo.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
        ammo.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 0

    }

    func createEnemy() {
        possibleEnemies = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: possibleEnemies) as! [String]
        let randomDistribution = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 50, highestValue: 736)

        enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: possibleEnemies[0])
        enemy.name = "enemy"
        enemy.position = CGPoint(x: 1200, y: randomDistribution.nextInt())
        addChild(enemy)

        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: enemy.texture!, size: enemy.size)
        enemy.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisonType.enemy.rawValue
        enemy.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisonType.player.rawValue | CollisonType.ammo.rawValue

        enemy.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: -300, dy: 0)
        enemy.physicsBody!.angularVelocity = 5
        enemy.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
        enemy.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 0

    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        for node in children {
            if node.position.x < -300 || node.position.x > 1300 || node.position.y < -300 || node.position.y > 1000 {
                node.removeFromParent()
            }
        }

        if !isGameOver {
            score += 1
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        var location = touch.location(in: self)

        if location.y < 50 {
            location.y = 50
        } else if location.y > 730 {
            location.y = 730
        }

        player.position = location
    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        if contact.bodyA.node == player {
            playerCollided(with: contact.bodyB.node!)
        } else if contact.bodyB.node == player {
            playerCollided(with: contact.bodyA.node!)
        }

        if contact.bodyA.node == ammo {
            ammoCollided(with: contact.bodyB.node!)
        } else if contact.bodyB.node == ammo {
            ammoCollided(with: contact.bodyA.node!)
        }

    }

    func playerCollided(with node:SKNode) {
        if node.name == "enemy" {
            let explosion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "explosion")!
            explosion.position = enemy.position
            addChild(explosion)

            player.removeFromParent()
            enemy.removeFromParent()
            isGameOver = true
        }
    }

    func ammoCollided(with node:SKNode) {
        if node.name == "enemy" {
            let explosion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "explosion")!
            explosion.position = enemy.position
            addChild(explosion)

            ammo.removeFromParent()
            enemy.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead, and refactor your ___Collided code to adjust.

Don't test Node equality. Use the name or .categoryBitMask to figure out what kind of node it is.

get the categoryBitMask in this tutorial ; https://www.raywenderlich.com/145318/spritekit-swift-3-tutorial-beginners

or try this;

player.name = "player1"

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        if contact.bodyA.node.name == "player1" {
            playerCollided(with: contact.bodyB.node!)
        } else if contact.node.name == "player1" {
            playerCollided(with: contact.bodyA.node!)
        }

        if contact.bodyA.node.name == "ammo" {
            ammoCollided(with: contact.bodyB.node!)
        } else if contact.node.name == "ammo" {
            ammoCollided(with: contact.bodyA.node!)
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it still does not work completely. Only 3/4 of the bullets disappeared after collision (some still bounces around), as well as the player. But enemies don't ever disappear. Nor does explosion happen. Explosions only happen sporadically off to the right of the iPad (where its out of the range of player visibility). I will try and follow the tutorial link you provided. Thank you.

Comment: I followed the tutorial link and was able to solve my issue. Thanks again @eSpecialized!!